# hp laserjet pro mfp m127fw bug?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, printing

OS = Xubuntu 14.04

I just installed my new printer hp laserjet pro mfp m127fw via HPLIP and everything went fine till I wanted to print. I received this error :

hpcups crashed with sigabrt in_assert_fail_base()

I think it's a bug(?) :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1131854

Can anybody tell me how to get my printer working? (I am not very technical so please explain it in a simple way if possible ;-).) Thx!

Comment: Anybody? I actually can't miss my printer so a solution would be very welcome ;-). Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Since the bug you are reffering to is more than a year old and probably doesn't apply to 14.04 I would suggest to file a new bug report with ubuntu-bug from a terminal and provide as much detail as possible when the crash happens using these steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Reporting_an_application_crash_in_the_stable_release

Comment: Since I am not very technical I don't understand much of how to report the bug. Isn't there an easier way to report it?

Comment: Anybody home ;-)?